# How to make a multiplayer game from a beginner standpoint?

Tags: multiplayer

Hello everyone I don't have any experience with programming for a multiplayer game but does anyone know a good video tutorial or website that explains how to do this? I have already tried a few video series like these 2 but maybe there are some more out there that use different techniques or do a better job explaining.

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a3TtPr_yvI)
[rawkes link](http://rawkes.com/articles/creating-a-real-time-multiplayer-game-with-websockets-and-node.html)

Comment: You can check this (not yet released) book http://www.amazon.com/Multiplayer-Game-Programming-Architecting-Networked/dp/0134034309/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1436041194&sr=8-1&keywords=multiplayer+game+programming also you may be interested in this server service from Amazon  http://aws.amazon.com/game-hosting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i eventually used socket.io and watched a few tutorials from https://www.youtube.com/user/smithamilli
she explains how to make a chatroom but i used the same technique to make a multiplayer game

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YC6bNrkElc0 has a good introductory video in typical programming patterns for (Unity 3D) multiplayer games, using Exit Games Photon Network Engine.

Find the demos and other further explained in HammerLabs' videos at https://www.youtube.com/user/HammerLabs/videos.

No videos but a few links around multiplayer networking, multiplayer game programming in general as well as tutorials for Unity 3D are linked to from http://doc.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/tutorials/photon-unity-and-networking-links.

Comment: i'm looking more for a tutorial on how to build a game from scratch. i'd like to make the game myself not with unity. altough this is certainly in the right direction so i will read through a few of these.